How to find the appropriate CRS for shapefile with strange extent in QGIS
I have a shapefile that I need to import. It has an extent as follows:
6070755.0197066366672516,2191083.7598814815282822 : 6213671.7394500551745296,2236821.9991134637966752
The layer does not have a CRS upon import.
I am working to assign a projection and reproject this layer (or otherwise fix it) to work with a 3857 pseudo-mercator projection. What is the best method to do this based on the extent?
When I upload the layer as-is, it is not found on the map based on use of QMS topo map (3857). After reprojecting the layer, it is found in the wrong location.

There's a plugin called projguesser (or similar) that can help, but the metadata should tell you what the projection is

The metadata does not have the projection and it does not have a .prj file.

without know (at least) where it should be we can't really help - can you add some more information and a link to the file if possible

I found a great solution on reddit that I didn't know existed. QGIS has a Find Projection function, which provides an output of possibilities for the CRS. With that list, you can assign each CRS until your layer appears in the correct location. Issue solved!

Then you should answer your question so we can upvote it for you

Solution: Using the 'Find Projection' function in the processing toolbox on QGIS. Zoom in so your project area is in the window. Running the function (a QGIS built-in) will produce a list of potential projections as an attribute table. Assign each CRS to your layer, one by one, until you find the one that geo-locates your GIS data to the correct spot.
This method requires knowledge of where your data are supposed to be. I had other layers for the project that I cross-referenced as I assigned projections to my layer.
